# How to create skip functionality pygame?

Tags: python, loops, pygame, skip

I'm trying to create a way in pygame for the player to skip the tutorial phase simply by pressing "escape". However, I can't seem to get it to work when using the following:

```
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        brek2 = True
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        run = False
                        run2 = False
                        brek = True
                if brek or brek2:
                    break
                pygame.time.delay(1000)
            if brek:
                break
```

Here's the full loop of the tutorial phase if you need it:

```
        while run2:
                # intro sequence
                pygame.event.pump()
                fade(screen_width, screen_height, BLACK)
                fade(screen_width, screen_height, WHITE)
                techi = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("Techi-Joe.gif"), (75, 75))
                bg = pygame.Surface((screen_width, screen_height))
                bg.fill(WHITE)
                win.blit(pygame.transform.scale(bg, (screen_width, screen_height)), (0, 0))
                win.blit(techi, (100, 600))
                pygame.display.update()
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        run = False
                        run2 = False
                pygame.time.delay(1000)
                brek2 = False
                presss = 1
                brek = False
                techi_bubble = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("techi_speech_bubble.png"), (700, 350))
                techi_font = pygame.font.Font('Consolas.ttf', 25)
                for a in range(len(techi_says)):
                    win.blit(pygame.transform.scale(bg, (screen_width, screen_height)), (0, 0))
                    win.blit(techi_bubble, (175, 300))
                    win.blit(techi, (100, 600))
                    writeLikeCode(techi_says[a], 235, 350, techi_font, 20)
                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                            brek2 = True
                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            run = False
                            run2 = False
                            brek = True
                    if brek or brek2:
                        break
                    pygame.time.delay(1000)
                if brek:
                    break
```

Here's some addition code referenced as function writeLikeCode:

```
techi_says = ["Hello, User!", "My name is Techi-Joe.", "I'm a programmer,", "and this is my first game:",
          "Dunk the Chief!", "in Dunk the Chief,", "your main objective", "is to dunk any US president", "you choose",
          "in a cold tub of water!", "yay!"]


# writeLikeCode function
def writeLikeCode(string, xpos, ypos, font, fontsize):
    for x in range(len(string)):
        lstring = split(string)
        text = font.render(lstring[x], 1, GREEN)
        win.blit(text, (xpos + (x * fontsize), ypos))
        pygame.time.delay(50)
        pygame.display.update()
```

and here's the split function:

```
def split(string):
    return [char for char in string]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) does not only get the events, It also removes the events from the event queue. If you call `pygame.event.get()` twice in a row, then the first call will retrieve the events, but the 2nd call returns an empty list.

> ```py
> for event in pygame.event.get(): # returns the list of events
>    # [...]
> for event in pygame.event.get(): # returns empty list
>    # [...]
> ```

If the event occurs after between the 2 calls of `pygame.event.get()`, then the event will be received be the 2nd call. But that will be a rare case.

`pygame.K_ESCAPE` is not an event type (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)), it is a key see ([`pygame.key`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html)).
If you want to detect if the <kbd>ESC</kbd> was pressed, then you have to detect the `KEYDOWN` event and to evaluate if the `.key` attribute is `K_ESCAPE`. e.g:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False
        run2 = False
        brek = True

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            brek2 = True
```